# Flex ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sdk

There is no problem when I complied a Flex project with Flex SDK 4.0 or 4.1. But when I switch to SDK 4.5 (Because our group begins to use flash builder 4.5), I got the error when open a window ( pop up a widget window). I searched online for several days, but still have no clue what caused the problem.

Please help.

Here is the error message:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData.
at flash.display::BitmapData/ctor()
at flash.display::BitmapData()
at spark.effects.supportClasses::AnimateTransitionShaderInstance/play()
at spark.effects.supportClasses::AnimateInstance/startEffect()
at mx.effects::Effect/play()
at mx.core::UIComponent/commitCurrentState()
at mx.core::UIComponent/commitProperties()
at spark.components.supportClasses::GroupBase/commitProperties()
at spark.components::Group/commitProperties()
at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()
at spark.components::Group/validateProperties()
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()
```

Here is the mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("widgets.BatchGeocoder.components.AddressMapper")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <!-- SkinParts
    name=ddlCityField, type=spark.components.DropDownList, required=true
    name=ddlCountryField, type=spark.components.DropDownList, required=true
    name=ddlAddressField, type=spark.components.DropDownList, required=true
    name=ddlStateField, type=spark.components.DropDownList, required=true
    name=ddlZipField, type=spark.components.DropDownList, required=true
    name=btnSubmit, type=spark.components.Button, required=true
    -->
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="5"
                          horizontalAlign="center" />
    </s:layout>
    <s:Group width="100%"
             height="100%">
        <s:Label x="5"
                 y="10"
                 text="Address: " />
        <s:DropDownList x="100"
                        y="5"
                        id="ddlAddressField"/>
        <s:Button x="250"
                  y="5"
                  label="x"
                  fontSize="4"
                  width="22"
                  height="22"
                  toolTip="Reset Address Field"
                  skinClass="widgets.BatchGeocoder.components.skins.RefreshButtonSkin"
                  click="ddlAddressField.selectedIndex = -1" />

        <s:Label x="5"
                 y="40"
                 text="City: " />
        <s:DropDownList x="100"
                        y="35"
                        id="ddlCityField"/>
        <s:Button x="250"
                  y="35"
                  label="x"
                  fontSize="4"
                  width="22"
                  height="22"
                  toolTip="Reset City Field"
                  skinClass="widgets.BatchGeocoder.components.skins.RefreshButtonSkin"
                  click="ddlCityField.selectedIndex = -1"/>

        <s:Label x="5"
                 y="70"
                 text="State: " />
        <s:DropDownList x="100"
                        y="65"
                        id="ddlStateField"/>
        <s:Button x="250"
                  y="65"
                  label="x"
                  fontSize="4"
                  width="22"
                  height="22"
                  toolTip="Reset State Field"
                  skinClass="widgets.BatchGeocoder.components.skins.RefreshButtonSkin"
                  click="ddlStateField.selectedIndex = -1" />

        <s:Label x="5"
                 y="100"
                 text="Zip: " />
        <s:DropDownList x="100"
                        y="95"
                        id="ddlZipField"/>
        <s:Button x="250"
                  y="95"
                  label="x"
                  fontSize="4"
                  width="22"
                  height="22"
                  toolTip="Reset Zip Code Field"
                  skinClass="widgets.BatchGeocoder.components.skins.RefreshButtonSkin"
                  click="ddlZipField.selectedIndex = -1" />

        <s:Label x="5"
                 y="130"
                 text="Country: " />
        <s:DropDownList x="100"
                        y="125"
                        id="ddlCountryField"/>
        <s:Button x="250"
                  y="125"
                  label="x"
                  fontSize="4"
                  width="22"
                  height="22"
                  toolTip="Reset Country Field"
                  skinClass="widgets.BatchGeocoder.components.skins.RefreshButtonSkin"
                  click="ddlCountryField.selectedIndex = -1" />

        <s:Label x="5"
                 y="160"
                 text="Label: " />
        <s:DropDownList x="100"
                        y="155"
                        id="ddlLabelField"/>
        <s:Button x="250"
                  y="155"
                  label="x"
                  fontSize="4"
                  width="22"
                  height="22"
                  toolTip="Reset Label Field"
                  skinClass="widgets.BatchGeocoder.components.skins.RefreshButtonSkin"
                  click="ddlLabelField.selectedIndex = -1" />
    </s:Group>
    <s:Button id="btnSubmit"
              label="Done" />
</s:Skin>
```

**---------------------------------------------**
Thanks. I do have the skin. the problem is why it works with SDK 4.1, not with SDK 4.5.
Here is the skin definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="down" />
        <s:State name="over" />
        <s:State name="up" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- SkinParts
    name=labelDisplay, type=spark.components.supportClasses.TextBase, required=false
    -->
    <s:Group id="holder">
        <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../../assets/images/GenericRefresh16.png')"
                       source.over="@Embed('../../assets/images/GenericRefresh16_active.png')" />
    </s:Group>

    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition>
            <s:CrossFade target="{holder}" />
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>

</s:Skin>
```

---

Thanks. Unfortunately, it does not work.
But you are right, the crossfade effect caused the problem.I removed the following piece code, and it works.

```
<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition autoReverse="true">
        <s:CrossFade target="{holder}"/>
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```

Any idea. Please help.

Comment: Do you have an Image in your RefreshButton skin? If so, I think the skin code could be more useful

Comment: **I am only allowed to add the comments to my post. I add the code in the original  post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing from the stack trace, the crossfade effect seems to be the problem. Try this instead :

```
<s:Group id="holder">
    <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../../assets/images/GenericRefresh16.png')"
                   visible.over="false" />
    <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('../../assets/images/GenericRefresh16_active.png')"
                   visible.over="true" />
</s:Group>

<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition autoReverse="true">
        <s:CrossFade target="{holder}"/>
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```